# Maven Java EE Configuration Marker with Java Server Faces 1.2

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e, dwm

I'm having a weird configuration problem with Maven in Eclipse. Although I can build the project and deploy it to tomcat without any errors, The Marker tab keeps showing the following message:

```
[-] Maven Java EE Configuration Problem
(x) JavaServer Faces 1.2 can not be installed : One or more constraints have not been satisfied.
(x) JavaServer Faces 1.2 requires Dynamic Web Module 2.5 or newer.
```

I am in fact using Dynamic Web Module 2.4, which would be the source of the message. I would need to change it to at least 2.5 to work with JSF. Problem is, I'm not even using JSF.

So, probably one of the project's dependencies needs it. I ran the following command to find out the dependency tree for my project:

```
mvn dependency:tree -DoutputFile=<i>/path/to/outputFile/dependencies.txt</i>
```

and surprise! No JSF 1.2 mentioned.

**EDIT** Forgot to add my PC setup:

OS: Ubuntu 12.10

Eclipse: 4.2 SR1

Java: jdk1.5.0_22 and jdk1.7

Apache Maven: 3.0.4

Maven home: /usr/share/maven

m2e: 1.3.1.20130219-1424

m2e-wtp: 0.17.0.20130212-1821

None of my co-workers are having this issue. Two of them use Windows, two use Ubuntu 12.10. One of them uses Eclipse 4.2, others use Eclipse 3.7. So apparently this is either has to do with 4.2SR1 or with my project setup. But I can't find where the problem is.

Here's my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>edited</groupId>
    <artifactId>edited</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>edited</version>
    <name>edited</name>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>deployment</id>
            <name>Internal Releases</name>
            <url>http://edited/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>deployment</id>
            <name>Internal Releases</name>
            <url>http://edited/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Testes com Junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Testes Funcionais com cucumber-jvm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mockito para criar mocks e stubs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Fixture Factory Test Data Builder -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.fixturefactory</groupId>
            <artifactId>fixture-factory</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jasper Reports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Struts 2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts.xwork</groupId>
            <artifactId>xwork-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-jasperreports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Banco de dados Mysql + Hibernate + c3p0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId> <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId> 
            <version>2.2.7</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId> 
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId> <version>2.2.6</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.36</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Especificação do Java EE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javaee</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache Commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Templating -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-compat</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker-gae</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Quartz Scheduler -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Geração de Código -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Xstream -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- RestEasy -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Xfire -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>xfire-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JQuery -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>edited</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I had the same problem. After adding velocity dependencies in my maven project i was getting the same error in marker tab. Then I noticed that the web.xml file that maven project creates has servlet2.3 schema. When i changed it to servlet 3.0 schema and save the project then this error gone. Here is the web.xml file that maven creates

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

Change it to

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
                        version="3.0">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

</web-app>
```

save the project, and your error would gone.

After that if markers tab is still showing message then Select the project. Do mouse right click. Select Maven --> Update Project.

Hopefully error would be gone then.

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

I too had the same problem.

The solution for me was to add following in the [pom.xml](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#What_is_the_POM) as suggested [here](http://micharg.blogspot.in/2011/11/eclipsemaven-error-dynamic-web-module.html).

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: This may be a solution to some problem, but it's not a solution to the poster's problem. It has nothing to do with JSF or the Dynamic Web Module version.

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem.  I was working on a project where I did not control the web.xml configuration file, so I could not use the changes suggested about altering the version.  Of course the project was not using JSF so this was especially annoying for me.

I found that there is a ***really simple fix***.  Go to Preferences > Maven > Java EE Itegration and uncheck the "JSF Configurator" box.

I did this in a fresh workspace before importing the project again, but it may work equally as well on an existing project ... not sure.

Comment: Fantastic! In my case, I needed only to alter the configuration as suggested, remove and re-import the project from Eclipse. Cheers!

Comment: This really should be the accepted answer since it provides a solution to the real problem: a Eclipse bug. It just seems wrong to me change or overwhelm something in a project just because an IDE is forcing you to without even give a reason.

Answer (score 8):

I have encountered this with Maven projects too. This is what I had to do to get around the problem:

First update your web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
                    version="3.0">
<display-name>Servlet 3.0 Web Application</display-name>
```

Then right click on your project and select Properties -> Project Facets In there you will see the version of your Dynamic Web Module. This needs to change from version 2.3 or whatever to version 2.5 or above (I chose 3.0).

However to do this I had to uncheck the tick box for Dynamic Web Module -> Apply, then do a Maven Update on the project. Go back into the Project Facets window and it should already match your web.xml configuration - 3.0 in my case. You should be able to change it if not.

If this does not work for you then try right-clicking on the Dynamic Web Module Facet and select change version (and ensure it is not locked).

Or you can follow this steps:

1. Window > Show View > Other > General > navigator
2. There is a .settings folder under your project directory
3. Change the dynamic web module version in this line to 3.0
4. Change the Java version in this line to 1.5 or higher

don't forget to update your project

Hope that works!

Comment: I did all the steps but forgot to "Maven update" which was what fixed it for me

Comment: The "uncheck" Dynamic Web Module to apply is what I was missing. This worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

After changing lots in my POM and updating my JDK I was getting the "One or more constraints have not been satisfied" related to Google App Engine. The solution was to *delete the Eclipse project settings and reimport it*.

On OS X, I did this in Terminal by changing to the project directory and

```
rm -rf .project
rm -rf .settings
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check your project facets in the project configuration. This is where you may uncheck the JSF dependency.

[image]

Comment: Hi Torsten, thanks for the answer. JavaServer Faces is not selected in my Project Facets.

Is Maven by any chance ignoring my setup and enforcing it?

Comment: Strange indeed. Did you try deleting the Problem marker? Does it reappear after Maven / Update Project ... ? How does your .stettings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml file compare to one of your co-workers?

Comment: This would be in the responsibility of the m2e-wtp plugin then. Without more details about the project its hard to guess what might be causing this. Have you crosschecked with an earlier version of the plugin?

Comment: What details would you need?
I'll add the pom.xml file

Answer (score 2):

The m2e plugin generate project configuration every time when you update project (Maven->Update Project ...
That action overrides facets setting configured manually in Eclipse. Therefore you have to configure it on pom level. By setting properties in pom file you can tell m2e plugin what to  do.

Enable/Disable the JAX-RS/JPA/JSF Configurators at the pom.xml level
The optional JAX-RS, JPA and JSF configurators can be enabled or disabled at a workspace level from Window > Preferences > Maven > Java EE Integration. Now, you can have a finer grain control on these configurators directly from your pom.xml properties :

Adding false in your pom properties section will disable the JAX-RS configurator
Adding false in your pom properties section will disable the JPA configurator
Adding false in your pom properties section will disable the JSF configurator
The pom settings always override the workspace preferences. So if you have, for instance the JPA configurator disabled at the workspace level, using true will enable it on your project anyway. (http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E-WTP/New_and_Noteworthy/1.0.0)

Comment: m2eclipse was also selecting the JSF facet for me even though it wasn't a JSF project. This solution was good.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse is buggy on factes screen and at times doesn't update the config files in workspace. There are two options one can try  :

1. Go to org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml file located inside .settings folder of  eclipse project. Go and manually delete the JSF facet entry. you can also update other facets as well.
2. Right click project and go to properties->Maven-->Java EE Integeration. choose options : enable project specific settings, Enable Java EE configuration, Maven archiver generates files under the build directory

Answer (score 0):

the same solution as [Basit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1000510/basit) .. but **the version 3.0 doesn't work for me**
try this .. **it works for me to integrate struts 2.x**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>blabla</display-name>
...
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an older thread,but I will post my answer for others.
I have to recreate the project in a different workspace after the changes to make it work, as discussed in [JavaServer Faces 2.2 requires Dynamic Web Module 2.5 or newer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22361005/javaserver-faces-2-2-can-not-be-installed)

Answer (score 0):

The below steps should be the simple fix to your problem

> 1. Project->Properties->ProjectFacet-->Uncheck jsf apply and OK.
> 2. Project->Maven->UpdateProject-->This will solve the issue.

Here while on Updating Project Maven will automatically chooses the Dynamic web module