# JavaServer Faces 2.2 requires Dynamic Web Module 2.5 or newer

Tags: eclipse, maven, jsf, configuration

I tried few things, but still this problem persists. I am using Eclipse Kepler. I get following error on importing maven project

> JavaServer Faces 2.2 can not be installed : One or more constraints have not been satisfied
>
> JavaServer Faces 2.2 requires Dynamic Web Module 2.5 or newer

1) I tried few things as mentioned in [Maven Java EE Configuration Marker with Java Server Faces 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115009/maven-java-ee-configuration-marker-with-java-server-faces-1-2), but no luck.
2)Also I went into .settings and modified org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml and modified jst.web to point to 2.5 or 3.0 version; but I get some other errors.

I am trying to make Sencha GXT examples work in maven/eclipse build based on http://neiliscoding.blogspot.ie/2012/05/how-to-setup-examples-for-use-in-gxt-3.html and having this javaserver faces problem in eclipse. 
Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<!-- POM file generated with GWT webAppCreator -->
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <artifactId>xx</artifactId>
    <groupId>ss</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>guis</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>GWT Maven Archetype</name>

<properties>
    <!-- Convenience property to set the GWT version -->
    <gwtVersion>2.5.1</gwtVersion>
    <!-- GWT needs at least java 1.5 -->
    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>gin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <classifier>sources</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sencha.gxt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gxt-chart</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sencha.gxt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gxt</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sencha.gxt</groupId>
        <artifactId>uibinder-bridge</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>

<build>
    <!-- Generate compiled stuff in the folder used for developing mode -->
    <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <plugins>

        <!-- GWT Maven Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                        <!-- <goal>i18n</goal> -->
                        <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see gwt-maven-plugin 
                documentation at codehaus.org -->
            <configuration>
                <runTarget>guis.html</runTarget>
                <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
                <i18nMessagesBundle>com.harmonia.client.Messages</i18nMessagesBundle>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Copy static web files before executing gwt:run -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <!-- <goals> <goal>exploded</goal> </goals> -->
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is my web.xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!-- <!DOCTYPE web-app
 PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app> -->

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
                    version="3.0">
<display-name>GXT Created Web Application</display-name>



<!-- Default page to serve -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>guis.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

As you can see, I tried different dtds in above web.xml, but I still have the problem. Would appreciate any hints

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your problem is that you have marked your web.xml as being servlet 2.3 compliant (or perhaps not even that - I am not sure how your doctype in a comment is interpreted)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!-- <!DOCTYPE web-app
 PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
```

and you need it to be at least servlet 2.5 compliant for the Eclipse tooling to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

(untested - copied from http://javahowto.blogspot.dk/2009/10/sample-webxml-servlet-25.html)

You may need to recreate the Eclipse project to have the changes picked up.

Comment: thanks. Recreating in new workspace helped me. Tried few things like maven update and reimporting the project into same workspace (but these didnot help)

Comment: Why when I do this I get this Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer ???

Comment: @It_Does_Not_Matter Use Glassfish.

Answer (score 32):

I have encountered this with Maven projects too.  This is what I had to do to get around the problem:

First update your web.xml as mentioned Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen.  I used version 3.0 as below:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
                        version="3.0">
    <display-name>Servlet 3.0 Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

Then right click on your project and select Properties -> Project Facets
In there you will see the version of your Dynamic Web Module.  This needs to change from version 2.3 or whatever to version 2.5 or above (I chose 3.0).

However to do this I had to uncheck the tick box for Dynamic Web Module -> Apply, then do a Maven Update on the project.  Go back into the Project Facets window and it should already match your web.xml configuration - 3.0 in my case. You should be able to change it if not.

If this does not work for you then try right-clicking on the Dynamic Web Module Facet and select change version (and ensure it is not locked).

Hope that works!

Comment: Thanks for posting this solution. It worked for me too! 

And an additional warning to GWT developers: Remember whenever you tweak eclipse dialogs your project class path will get messed up again (eclipse does it, M2Eclipse, or Mojo plugin) and you will need to go back into your project "Build Path" dialog again (source tab) and make sure the entry that ends with "../src/main/resources' has "Exclude: (None)", or else your [module].gwt.xml file will become 'unfindable' again by eclipse and stuff will quit working (namely debugging)

Comment: :* this worked for me and saved me potentially hours of wasted time. Also, tip for those new to maven like myself: to update Maven, right click on your project and look for the maven sub menu. In there, you will find an option to run the update ('Update Project' for me).

Comment: This also saved my day. Trick is easy to miss - to uncheck the facets/dynamic web module box in order to be able to change its version, which isn't exactly intuitive. Thanks!

Comment: Just a note to others who may have this problem and this fix isn't working. I tried this with a generic Eclipse Proton install that had a space in the installation directory. I reinstalled Eclipse EE web edition with no space and did this fix and it worked first time.

Comment: It worked for AWS beanstalk eclipse plugin :-) thx!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and in my web.xml had version 2.5 while the project had the (right-click on Project-> Properties-> Progect Facets->) Dynamic Web Module 2.3. Although I tried to change the version from 2.3 to 2.5 ECLIPSE did not permit it.

`Solution:` I removed the check mark under the heading Dynamic Web Module, I saved and I had Update Project. Automatically re-awakening is entering the box with the correct version.

Answer (score 3):

The solution that i had found for this problem is

1 ) Right Click on the Project >Properties>Uncheck Dynamic Web Module>Apply And Close.

2 ) Right Click on the Project>Maven>Update Project...

Comment: This worked for me and seems to be the cleanest current solution - I did not have those entries in my web.xml that are mentioned in earlier answers)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and I have solved as following:

**STEP 1:** Update web.xml file, and add the following codes

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
</web-app>
```

**STEP 2** : Write click on the project folder, and select ***Properties*** then search *"Project Facets"* . You need to uncheck "Dynamic Web Module", then Apply and then close it. 
[See Eclipse properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzClQ.png)

**STEP 3**: Update your Maven, then you good to go.

Answer (score 1):

My own solution was to put the rignt dependency in the pom.xml.

If the project is declared as a 3.1 Web Dynamic Project in the facets, then the java.servlet-api dependency also has to be the 3.1.0 (or 3.1.x) version.

In my case I had left 3.0.1 version, thus inducing this specific error message in the "Problems" view :

Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 3.0.
  One or more constraints have not been satisfied.

(of course make sure in addition that your web.xml must also be the 3.1 one).

Answer (score 1):

My project was facing the same issue. I changed the web.xml as follows:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
                    version="3.0">
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
```

The error persisted. But after following the suggestions made in the following link, the issue was resolved.

http://crunchify.com/how-to-fix-cannot-change-version-of-project-facet-dynamic-web-module-to-3-0-error-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 1):

Try this :
Delete your project in Eclipse. Delete the Eclipse project, not your application! It should disappear from the list of projects.
In Windows Explorer locate your project directory and delete the directories .settings and target (if found) and delete the files .project and .classpath.
Back to Eclipse, import existing Maven project. That is all!

Assuming that your web.xml has the right header <web-app> to your target JSF version.

Answer (score 0):

**Open your project’s pom.xml and add this plugin tag
Finally, right click on your project > Maven > Update Project…

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
```

**

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen's answer didn't help as I was already at Dynamic Web Module 2.5.  I had run into this same issue years before and given up.  Deciding to re-investigate what I first did was try and remove support for "Dynamic Web Module" by unchecking it - but hey, it's locked?  So I unlocked it and disabled/unchecked it.  I then unlocked JavaServer Faces, unchecked it as well, clicked apply - no explosion!  With fingers crossed I then re-checked Dynamic Web Module and set it to 3.1.  I then re-checked JavaServer Faces setting it to 2.2.  Clicked apply - no "big badda boom", it worked - profit!  Hope this helps anyone else with the same problem, also it doesn't rely on adjusting XML files.

Note I also did set the java faceted version to 1.8 as well as it was required.

Answer (score 0):

For me none of previous worked.

Then I found this link:
https://crunchify.com/how-to-fix-cannot-change-version-of-project-facet-dynamic-web-module-to-3-0-error-in-eclipse/

for me was almost the same as described in that link.

- Go to your Eclipse Workspace location
- Open file /.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml.
- Modify version for jst.web property to 2.5
- Back in eclipse
- Right click on Project
- Refresh
- Click on Project
- Select Clean
- Right-click on project name
- Click on Maven
- Update project

Problems gone for me

Answer (score 0):

I follow the next steps.

*Right click on project -> Properties -> Project Facets*. Mark *Dynamic Web Module*, *JavaServer Faces* and choose the versions of your project. (If you get the message *Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module* follow the next tutorial [How to fix Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module](https://crunchify.com/how-to-fix-cannot-change-version-of-project-facet-dynamic-web-module-to-3-0-error-in-eclipse/))

Delete the ***web.xml*** file, then *right click on project -> Java EE Tools -> Generate Deployment Descriptor Stub*.

Delete the project from eclipse (don't delete the sources), then at the project root level execute:

```
mvn eclipse:clean
mvn eclipse:eclipse
mvn clean install -X
```

Import the project again as *Existing Maven Projects*.

My web.xml looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
    version="4.0">
    <display-name>jsf-sample</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```