# Maven configuration issue one or more constraints have not been satisfied

Tags: java, maven, jsf

Got the following error while trying to build our common code.

`Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
JavaServer Faces 2.0 can not be installed : One or more constraints have not been satisfied.    Apps        line 1  Maven Java EE Configuration Problem
JavaServer Faces 2.0 requires Dynamic Web Module 2.5 or newer.  Apps        line 1  Maven Java EE Configuration Problem`

I tried to find the error inside the code but there is no error. I suspect it's a dependency that is missing. Could someone please explain further if my thoughts are correct?

Comment: What is "our common code"?

Comment: Paste your `pom.xml`. Also, what prompted the career change?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/18632054/378633

Answer (score 5):

Somewhere in your project there is a `web.xml` descriptor, and it declares version number for compliance with some edition of servlet-api. 
Your application tries to use JSF2 which requires `web.xml` to declare version 2.5 or newer.
Apparently yours is too old.

Find this file and check what's there in the root element `<web-app>`.
There are examples of this descriptor for version 2.5 and 3 here on SO: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115009/maven-java-ee-configuration-marker-with-java-server-faces-1-2), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22361005/javaserver-faces-2-2-can-not-be-installed), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146247/java-web-app-what-determines-my-servlet-api-version-does-it-get-specified-in).